# How to deal with dm-verity on a Samsung S7 Edge when installing a custom recovery like TWRP

Tags: twrp, system-apps, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, dm-verity

I'm just starting to explore how to customize my Samsung S7 Edge and I'm interested in moving an application over to the system partition. It's currently running Android 8.0. I've been doing a lot of research on the process before I just dive in and I feel like I have a good understanding of the process using ODIN, installing TWRP for my particular device, and using TWRP to move the installed app into the system partition.

However, what I'm struggling to find detailed information on is `dm-verity` and if/how it would impact what I want to do. I know my device utilizes it, but the sources I'm reading boil things down to "download and install this file using ODIN" and provide a handy link to the file *without talking about the file at all* or otherwise explaining what is being changed. I struggle to find those sources trustworthy since the file details are completely unknown.

I'm assuming I'll need to circumvent `dm-verity` in order to utilize TWRP. Is this assumption correct and, if yes, what are the detailed steps to do so?

Answer (score 0):

For a Galaxy S7 Edge it is possible to root Android 7, and 8. It just apparently takes an engineering bootloader to do so. And I don't even think it is a REAL ENG Bootloader.

I agree with you however, most people in the XDA community that releases anything for a newer-ish samsung device gives little to zero information about what it is their files are even doing to your device.

Like seriously. Chainfire quitted working on Samsung Devices, and now all the big whig samsung devs, WILL NOT divulge their information to other devs.

Because some of the big devs will never own my device, but I can't work on my device because other devs won't share their knowledge, "because if they aren't going to do it, then no one is", apparently.

I had a real eng firmware for the Galaxy Note 5. The same thing they used on the Galaxy S8, but all those same devs laughed at me, and then stole my idea.

I will say JRKRUSE has some good, legit files for you to use on XDA, just don't expect him to explain anything at all. He keeps all his information to himself. Kind of like the S8 devs. Always general information, nothing specific.

But so far TWRP hasn't been officially flashed to a USA Galaxy S7/Edge device. And I think it is because of TWRP itself being so configured for default AOSP Android and not Samsung Android.